# keeping an instance of an object avaliable throughout an entire application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Yesterday i was given a project in my summer internships requiring the use of both XAML and C# in visual studios 2010 to make a WPF version of a Console Application i had created. unfortunately i had no experience in either language until 3 days ago, so while the solution to this problem may be simple it escapes me and i haven't been able to find any usable solutions online

essentially, when i start this WPF application i want to instantiate an object that is defined inside the application in C#. i want this instance of the class to be available for the entire time that the application is running. i was wondering if this could be accomplished by creating a global resource for the application, but as far as i can tell that can only be done for XAML resources.

any help and ideas would be appreciated. if anything i wrote is too ambiguous please let me know and i will try to clarify

Comment: My guess is that you want a `static` variable.

Comment: Two approaches:  dependency injection or static services.  Which are you envisioning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources are normally used for XAML type things (styles, converter instances and the like).

This seems like a good use case for a static class. Static classes are instantiated the first time they are used and there is only ever one instance. You can also use a singleton (which generally takes advantage of a static member).

Note that singletons *can* be a code smell, but if you know you need one, go ahead and make it! A resource isn't the way to go here though.

A quick singleton example:

```
public class MyGlobalClass
{
    private Lazy<MyGlobalClass> _instance = new Lazy<MyGlobalClass>();
    public static MyGlobalClass Instance { get { return _instance.Value; } }

    //Whatever else, accessed by MyGlobalClass.Instance.<Whatever>
}
```

Comment: so i would create a constructor and then create a static instance of it in the constructor class?

Comment: @nwrobinson, you don't "create" static instances, the framework does that for you. You just use it, and it exists as an application-level object. The same effect is true in my explicit singleton example. Does that make sense? I'm happy to provide any information you need.

Comment: it may not be exactly what you explained, but your answer got me messing around with static things and i ended up creating a static class with static properties. does that essentially accomplish tthe same thing?

Comment: @nwrobinson Yes, that is the "static class" version of my example. The one advantage to my singleton example is that it can be dependency injected, while a standard static class cannot. Glad you got it working!

Comment: thank you for your help with this, i just have one more question to make sure im understanding how this works correctly-
i can create methods in this class and they will work only for this specific static object, correct?

Comment: Define "work". Static methods will use the static properties and fields (only one instance), and the access modifiers (public, private, protected, internal) still apply. Does that answer your question, I'm not sure what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like BradleyDotNet has the basic answer covered. Additionally, you may want to look into using an IoC container and having it manage the singleton instance. So no static, no implementing the singleton pattern, just let the IoC container handle that responsibility.

One other word of caution, static != thread safe so if there are multiple threads accessing your singleton object make sure thread safety is considered.

Comment: this program should never get complex enough to run into that issue. essentially it just allows users to upload logs files from the companies software, parses them, and then allows them to do things such as search or look at specific types of errors so they don't have to dredge through thousands, or in some case millions of lines of logs. really more about convenience then power

Comment: I just wrote something very similar and nope, no IoC :) Just curious - what kind of thing would be in this global object?

Comment: the logs being looked at, as well as the status of any filters the user may have put on the log. for example if LogParser.searchQuery = nvidia, the shown logs will only be logs the contain the phrase nvidia.